# 2 - 2ghz quad core processors or 2 - 3.0ghz dual core processors

Tags: central-processing-unit, multi-core

I'm trying to decide which spare server I should use to build a backup file/print server.  These are both Dell PE2950 machines that haven't been used in about a year or so.  One has 2 2.0 ghz quad core procs, and the other has 2 3.0 ghz dual core procs.  None of these are the Nehalem procs since they're 2-3 years old.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to ask us to compare two CPUs, you really should tell us which two CPUs they are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're expecting a hell of a lot of load I'd use the 2 x 3Ghz Duals so you can use the 2 x 2Ghz Quads for something that'll need it.

Answer (score 3):

Whichever one you go for, why not make it a virtual machine, so you can migrate it easily, plus be able to use some of the spare horsepower in the future?

Comment: I thought about that.  Our main file server is a VM, but I need to use all the available storage for this file server, plus I wouldn't want to waste a VMWare license on a host with a single VM.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the Quads. You don't typically have lots of computation load on a file/print server, and Quad core cpus tend to perform better in IO intensive situations. That way you can also save the faster CPU's for when you need a server for something more computationally intensive such as a build server.